# Is it possible to convert the output of the Encrypt[] function into binary digits?

Tags: binary, cryptography

I use the following code to generate a key and then use it to encrypt a simple string message. The output of the function Encrypt is an encrypted *object*. But I would rather convert this into binary digits (a long sequence of zeros and ones). Unfortunately, I am not able to do so. I tried to use the function `IntegerDigits[]`
but that did not work.
Thanks in advance!

```
key = GenerateSymmetricKey[];
message = "Hello world";
Encrypt[key, message]
```

Comment: Is this what you are after? `Encrypt[key, message]["Data"] // Normal // 
  IntegerDigits[#, 2, 8] & // Flatten`

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply! Well, yes that is what I am after. But then after the conversion to binary digits, how may I take back those same digits and decrypt them? Apparently, the `Decrypt[]` function is also expecting an encrypted object, not a sequence of binary digits.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I will turn Kuba's comment into an answer. The [`EncryptedObject`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EncryptedObject.html) you create using [`Encrypt`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Encrypt.html) contains the encrypted data and the initialization vector of the encryption method as a [`ByteArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ByteArray.html). These can be turned into an array of digits using [`Normal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Normal.html) and [`IntegerDigits`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerDigits.html).

```
key = GenerateSymmetricKey[];
message = "Hello world";
eobj = Encrypt[key, message];
bin = eobj["Data"] // Normal // IntegerDigits[#, 2, 8] & // Flatten;
initvec = 
  eobj["InitializationVector"] // Normal // IntegerDigits[#, 2, 8] & // Flatten;
```

Now you send `bin` and `initvec` to the receiver (or do what ever else you wanted to do with the binary digits). To decrypt the message you can create a new [`EncryptedObject`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EncryptedObject.html) and decrypt it:

```
eobj2 = EncryptedObject[Association[
     "Data" -> ByteArray[(FromDigits[#1, 2] & ) /@ ArrayReshape[bin, {16, 8}]], 
     "InitializationVector" -> ByteArray[(FromDigits[#1, 2] & ) /@ 
           ArrayReshape[initvec, {16, 8}]], 
     "OriginalForm" -> String]];
Decrypt[key, eobj2]
```

Note that I used [`ByteArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ByteArray.html), [`FromDigits`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FromDigits.html), and [`ArrayReshape`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayReshape.html) to reverse Kuba's [`Normal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Normal.html), [`IntegerDigits`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerDigits.html) and [`Flatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html), respectively.

Comment: Thank you for your help!